# Virtualisation vs Virtualization

Tags: orthography, ise-ize

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [***zation vs ***sation?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/707/zation-vs-sation)

So, there seem to be some contradicting opinions on this matter. Can anyone shed some light on this case?

Might be similar to visualize vs visualise, etc. I thought it might be a British vs American English matter.

Comment: :) Thanks! (To anyone who is interested, read the SU chat log!)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Virtualization* is used in American English, *virtualisation* is used in British English.

The *Oxford English Dictionary* reports *virtualization*, and *virtualisation* as alternative form.
The *New Oxford American Dictionary* only reports *virtualization*.

Comment: +1 - The moment we get more UK than USA visitors to SU, I am retagging! :)