# What is the difference between summarizes and summarises?

Tags: orthography, ise-ize

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“-zation” vs “-sation”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/707/zation-vs-sation)

> Each post has an indicator which summarises who the post is shared.

What is the difference between these two terms?
Should I write *summarises* or *summarizes*?

Comment: Related: [“-zation” vs “-sation”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/707/zation-vs-sation)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Compare the results from the COCA ([Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/)) to the results from the BNC ([British Natural Corpus](http://www.natcorp.ox.ac.uk/)):

```
        Summarize      Summarise
COCA    1135               10
BNC      199              264
```

- *Summarise* is more common in British English, where *summarize* can also be found frequently.
- *Summarize* is more common in American English, where *summarise* is rarely used.

---

Note: [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOS:SPELL/IZE) page in the Wikipedia contains a long list of words that end with "ize" or "ise" depending on whether the usage is American English or British English. You will find words like summarize(ise), organize(ise), authorize(ise) and many others there.