# Is "memorise" or "memorize" used more often around the world?

Tags: orthography

Is "memorise" or "memorize" used more often around the world?

Curious which is more popular, *memorise* or *memorize*.

Comment: This is answered in general at [What is the difference between summarizes and summarises?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/34037/what-is-the-difference-between-summarizes-and-summarises) and hardly merits a separate answer. Otherwise, this could go on for a long time.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I followed suit, but then I saw that your citation itself was closed [as a dupe of this one](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/707/2303).

Comment: @Robusto I usually cite the one with the answer I consider most appropriate when this happens, not necessarily the earliest.

Comment: Checking the earlier threads, once again I find that at least one informed response has NOT been given, yet the question is dismissed as "previously answered".János, in my official job, ("kulturni producent" in the EU art world), I have noticed over years of translating, proofreading, reading and writing official, academic and art-world texts in what you might call "Continental European English" that many of these alleged distinctions between British and American spellings are dubious. The teaching of English spelling and language in European countries is quite a political farce.

Comment: The character limit of these responses prevents me from continuing- but the thread is being closed anyway. So...just a word to the wise.

Comment: The use of *memorize* wit a "z" seems to be growing even in BrE writing post 1900. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=memorize%2Cmemorise&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmemorize%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmemorise%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Kris - Yay!  (A light at the end of a very long tunnel.)