# British English: "fantasise" or "fantasize"?

Tags: verbs, british-english, orthography, ise-ize

I would like to know which spelling is more common in the UK: *fantasise* or *fantasize*?

Comment: I think they might have used to phantasise.

Comment: Related: [“-zation” vs “-sation”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/707/zation-vs-sation)

Comment: Rule of thumb: Where there's a difference it always tends to be Americans who use "z", and English who use "s". e.g.organize/organise, realize/realise, recognize/recognise,...etc http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_and_British_English_spelling_differences#-ise.2C_-ize_.28-isation.2C_-ization.29

Comment: @Urbycoz: If by *where there is a difference* you mean when both the *-ise* and *-ize* forms exist, the latter is **always** American. No exceptions.

Comment: @Urbycoz: Actually, it's "z" for Americans, "s" for Australians, and most often both are accepted in Britain, though usage may vary depending on what parts of Britain you're talking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My 1983 Chambers gives the *-ise* spelling first, which seemed reasonable to me because I think the *-ize* one looks 'American'.

**But** my 1998 Chambers gives the *-ize* spelling first, so I guess I have to assume they've changed their tune in the interim. Note that this change is reflected for *all* relevant words in the later edition. As [this](http://www.whichenglish.com/articles/ize_or_ise.html) article points out, almost all British 'authorities' apart from OED (Oxford English Dictionary) have now adopted/endorsed the American standard.

For what it's worth, [NGram](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=fantasise,fantasize&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=6&smoothing=3) suggests that ever since the word[s] really started to take off in the 60s, *fantasize* has been more common even in British English. I think maybe the fact that it was so rarely used before has allowed Brits to take the 'easier' path of simply copying American usage; there's less historical usage to be swept under the carpet, *and* it seems to have been more used by Americans earlier on anyway, so it's only fair they get to say how we spell it.

Thanks to @Peter Shor for commenting that the 'original' British form was *phantasise*, as can be seen from [this](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=fantasise,phantasise&year_start=1800&year_end=1980&corpus=6&smoothing=3) NGram. In light of that, perhaps the 'pseudo-original' *fantasise* could be seen as an abortive attempt to mimic (a dying) 'standard' British spelling for historical reasons. Which failed/is failing because there simply isn't enough history to sustain that position.

Comment: phantasize;
verb;
variant spelling of fantasize (restricted to archaic uses or, in modern use, to the fields of psychology and psychiatry). According to the Mac OS Dictionary.

Comment: @Nerian: apropos which I note that even Americans don't seem to have espoused *fantasm* yet. So also *phantasise* is dying out, and *phantasize* should never have existed, **phantasm** is still out there in the wild!

Comment: @FumbleFingers: it's **phantom** and **phantasm,** even in the U.S., and since these words reinforce each other, I suspect it will stay that way. (Speaking of which, is there a difference between a *phantom* and a *phantasm*?)

Comment: @Peter Shor: I think a *phantom* is more "externally real" (albeit "supernatural"), whereas a *phantasm* is conjured up *within the mind of the beholder*, but I'll check some more. That'll be after listening to and laying the ghost of *Ultra-Vivaldi* on Curved Air's *Phantasmogoria*, which has been stuck in my head since you first mentioned **phantasise** (Grrr! :)

Comment: ...I can't find anything remotely like a definition to support my thoughts, but [this](http://www.marxists.org/reference/archive/feuerbach/works/essence/ec24.htm) discourse uses both, apparently in line with my distinction. Also, of course, *phantom* can be an adjective meaning "ghostly", whereas *phantasm* is always a "thing" (real or not, depending on whether it's viewed from the perspective of imagination or reason).

Comment: As used in radiology, [phantoms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaging_phantom) are real things.  In my experience they are never referred to as phantasms.  But of course this is not a mainline use of *phantom*, and might not be well-known.

Answer (score 7):

The spelling *fantasise* is originally British; and appears to be more prevalent in British literature than *fantasize* (34 instances of the former for every 20 of the latter) according to the [British National Corpus](https://www.english-corpora.org/bnc/).  (Thanks, @z7sg!)

Google NGrams is misleading here, showing that it is [not more common](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=fantasize,fantasise&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=6&smoothing=3) than *fantasize* in British literature; but since the database is not entirely accurate, its evidence must go disregarded in this case.

Comment: BNC says 34 vs 20, that it *is* more common.

Comment: [This](http://books.google.com/books?id=oHryAAAAMAAJ&q=%22fantasize%22&dq=%22fantasize%22&hl=en&ei=BU4kTub5CI628QOCl-zBAw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CD0Q6AEwAw) usage of *fantasize*, published 1890, looks like the authentic words of Matteo Bandello, Bishop of Agen, who died in 1562. Both spellings are very rare in early writing, and many instances of *fantasise* look like quirky spelling of *fantasies* anyway.

Comment: Further, take a look at the 'British English' books from this ngram.  Some of them have American authors.

Comment: @z7sg: I edited my answer to agree with BNC rather than Google; but I'm still curious.  Can you show me how you know BNC is more trustworthy?

Comment: @z7sg: So I should rollback my edit?  I'd appreciate knowing.  If I don't know who is trustworthy, I can't really give answers.  Thanks!

Comment: @drm65 However, I do believe that American books are published in the UK with American spellings, whereas the BNC is specifically composed from British English sources.

Comment: @z7sg: All I need to know is: are you wrong about ngrams?  Should I rollback to say that ngrams is right?

Comment: @drm65 Also, I subsequently used this: http://corpus.byu.edu/bnc/ to search only written material, and this reduced the number of instances of *fantasize* to 16.

Comment: @drm65 No, I believe I am not wrong and the results from the corpus (particularly relating to the particular language of the corpus) should be considered more reliable than the google books ngram.  Perhaps I will check this on meta.

Comment: @z7sg let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/849/discussion-between-drm65-and-z7sg)

Answer (score 0):

It is *fantasise* in <strike>British</strike> English.

The general rule with the Brits is to use s and not z.  The confusion with *fantasise* is that, as spoken, it includes the word *size* which makes one think it would be written with as with the American English version *fantasize*, but this is not the case.

Comment: Many people in Britain think that the *correct* way to spell things is usually with -ize, actually.  It's a bit of a fallacy that -ise is the 'British' way.

Comment: It's not a fallacy.  But the use of -ize is surprisingly common and not more so for this word than recognise, realise etc.  The speculation in this answer does not fit real usage patterns.

Comment: @Jez: the Americani*z*ation of British English is sadly unrelenting.

Comment: @z7sg It is really.  See this question and the answers about British English having -ize as the older spelling, and many respected dictionaries using it: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/707/zation-vs-sation

Comment: @Jez It is not a fallacy.  My source: usage statistics from the British National Corpus that show the -ise spellings are favoured.  The answer you refer to on the other hand, cites no source.

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_and_British_English_spelling_differences#-ise.2C_-ize_.28-isation.2C_-ization.29) supports Jez's & my belief that this is, at least in part, fallacious. *ise* tends to be more common in British because *ize* is seen as an 'Americanism'. However, the OED states that *ize* should be used for words of Greek origin and *ise* for words of French or Latin origin.

Answer (score 0):

"-ise" is commoner than -"ize" in British English, certainly.  But the answers that assume that -ize is purely an invasion by American are barking up the wrong tree; it has a long and honourable history in Britain.  My 1965 edition of Fowler has a long article, quoting the OED, which concludes that verbs derived from Greek (the vast majority of -ize/ise words) should follow the English *-ize* rather than the French *-ise*.  (It also includes the sentence "But the Oxford University Press, The Cambridge University Press, *The Times*, and American usage, in all of which -ize is the accepted form, carry authority enough to outweigh superior numbers": ah, the good old days.)

And there was an Inspector Morse mystery (though I forget the name), turning on the fact that an Oxford lecturer would never have written a note conataining 'organise' and 'realise'.

Answer (score 0):

Both 'fantasise' and 'fantasize' are equally correct in Standard British English. However, only 'fantasize' is permitted in standard American usage. The '-ize' suffix is *not* an Americanism, *not* nonstandard, and is more etymologically correct — that is, it is the older variant and closer to the original Greek. It is, however, less common in British English today, probably because it's perceived to be an Americanism.

Whatever spelling variant you use you ought to use it consistently throughout any given document.