# Can all verbs ending in "-ise" be written with the suffix "ize"?

Tags: etymology, word-usage, orthography, variants, ise-ize

Are there any "-*ise*" (or "-*yse*") words which **cannot** be (or are never) written using "-*ize*"?

I searched for prior questions, and came across:

- https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/47785/correct-use-of-ise-vs-ize-at-the-end-of-words
- https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/47785/correct-use-of-ise-vs-ize-at-the-end-of-words
- [Are the endings "-zation" and "-sation" interchangeable?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/707/are-the-endings-zation-and-sation-interchangeable)

But I have seen no mention of the rule I was taught at school, which is that while verbs derived from Greek may receive the "-*ize*" suffix, verbs derived from Latin may not. All the answers to the questions above simply focus on the fact that Americans prefer the "-*ize*" form and the British tend to use "-*ise*" for words with those endings.

Has usage changed in the 21st Century? Can we spell all the following verbs with "ize"?

- advertise
- advise
- paralyse
- analyse
- despise
- exercise
- revise
- supervise
- surprise
- compromise

If we can use either ending for some of the words, but not others, what is the governing rule?

Comment: [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/ize-ise-or-yse) covers this.

Comment: @Andrew Leach - I've gone through questions that you have answered so far and I have found that many of them are off-topic.  Some of them are elementary questions that should have been migrated to ELL. Others could have been answered using "commonly-available references".  I've seen double standards here all the time.  It's high time you guys set up detailed guidelines on when to close a question and make sure all moderators act accordingly.  Personal taste ("I like this question", "I have a good answer to this question") should be ignored.

Comment: Also, if all questions that can be answered somewhere else in the www were considered off-topic, there would be very few left. A question like this one, with a good answer (below) by tchrist, is certainly a good source of information for those who are not as erudite as you are.

Comment: But I quickly found the ODO reference, with all the verbs you mention, plus a link to an article discussing regional and  historical usage. This level of research, and evidence thereof, is taken as a prerequisite here. tchrist broadens your headline question, but also does give a few more verbs. But you could check individual ones yourself in a dictionary, if you're in doubt when writing.

Comment: True, but you have double standards.  I haven't checked you, but I can easily pick up questions answered by other erudite old-timers the answers to wich can easily be found elsewhere.  Not to mention elementary questions such as one that asks the difference between "me" and "myself".

Comment: That's not elementary at all. Have you actually read all the discussion? Even professional grammarians disagree over what's acceptable. // Admittedly, the site's not perfect. //  But these questions (re the spellings of the verbs, which is what you essentially asked) are covered well at the ODO and linked reference, and in the threads you actually link to.

Comment: I accept the fact that the answer could have been found elsewhere.  I'm not questioning that.  What I regret to see here is a lack of uniform behaviour when deciding to close a question.  Even individual high-rank guys such as yourself sometimes close a question and sometimes decide to answer a similar one.  How can we expect a uniform behaviour from the group if the individual members act inconsistently ?

Comment: There's normally a joint responsibility for such decisions. And yes, I agree that some decisions still seem arbitrary. But the other extreme is that silly questions, repeat questions, trivial questions, very basic questions ... be considered acceptable, which was never the purpose envisaged for this site. Your question is a good one, but has been addressed in part here before, and is not accompanied by any evidence of researching available websites. This makes it inappropriate in its present form _for this website_.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot just blindly change all *‑ise* words into *‑ize* words.

Beyond those you mention (which I notice includes *‑yse* words, too, which can **never** be written *‑ize*), there are also verbs like all these below which must always end in *‑ise*, never in *‑ize*.

I’ve conveniently sorted these right to left for you so that etymological hints pop out.

```
‪        precise
‪     circumcise
‪         incise
‪      subincise
‪      supercise
‪     eclaircise
‪        abscise
‪         excise
‪       paradise
‪     imparadise
‪     unparadise
‪    merchandise
‪           gise
‪      franchise
‪    affranchise
‪    effranchise
‪    enfranchise
‪ disenfranchise
‪   disfranchise
‪        coalise
‪           mise
‪         demise
‪       redemise
‪         remise
‪        premise
‪        promise
‪      unpromise
‪        surmise
‪   interdespise
‪           rise
‪          arise
‪        rearise
‪      hypocrise
‪        reprise
‪       comprise
‪        apprise
‪     enterprise
‪       forprise
‪     resurprise
‪         uprise
‪       decatise
‪       practise
‪     unpractise
‪         cotise
‪    readvertise
‪        mortise
‪       chastise
‪       readvise
‪      preadvise
‪      disadvise
‪      misadvise
‪         devise
‪       televise
‪        previse
‪      improvise
‪           wise
```

Comment: Is this an "American Answer" or a "British Answer" ?

Comment: @Luis Mu. Neither. Both. Immaterial. Wrong question.  Leading question.  Unanswerablizable. I promize you that nobody speaking or writing English be it North American or Insular or Antipodean will ever advize you to improvize your zeeïfized verbz. If you cannot devize any rulez that make sense to you, you will simply have to start to look them up until you have uzed them enough to remember which iz which, something that comez onze you practize them more. Televized wordz don’t count; only written onez lead to orthographic paradize.

Comment: @tchrist And yet, there's absolutely no problem reading and understanding what you've written in your comment. Crasy!

Comment: ......... precise?

Comment: ... Ah, you're addressing the other question. 'Verbs' is mentioned both in the Headline question and the body text.