# Alternate spelling of maximize & minimize

Tags: orthography

So I was writing a document for a piece of coursework and I started to struggle for the right words when I found this:

1. You can spell *'maximise'* as opposed to *'maximize'*.
2. The word *'maximalize*' exists, and is rarely spelt '*Maximalise*'.
3. You cannot spell *'minimalise'* instead of '*minimalize*'.
4. '*Minimize*' and '*minimise*' are there too, relative to '*maximize*' and '*maximise*'.

And so, I was wondering which is the '*more correct*' way of expressing something to be made *minimal* / *maximal*, and what difference does using Z's instead of S's make?

I have searched all of these and it seems very debatable, sometimes some of these words are corrected and other times they are not.

Comment: 3 is wrong: you can spell "minimalise". Any word with the **suffix** *-ize* can be re-spelled with *-ise* (but people generally expect an author to be consistent, and essentially all writers/publishers from the U.S. always use the *-ize* variant). See [Are the endings “-zation” and “-sation” interchangeable?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/707/are-the-endings-zation-and-sation-interchangeable) and the other questions linked to that question

Comment: As a general rule -ize is American English, -ise is British English.

Comment: As *contemporary British usage* @AndyT. The Pocket Oxford Dictionary I had at school has no "-ise" spellings of this sort.

Comment: @David - Oxford prefers -ize, [apparently because it's closer to the Greek root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxford_spelling). This has always confused me, as my understanding of the OED was that it recorded language as used, rather than attempted to define it.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, the notation with "z" is used in US English print and media, whereas the notation with "s" is British English.